# Can a (micro) black hole be used to make a microscope?

Tags: black-holes, gravitational-lensing

We have seen that black-holes can be used as a telescope. Is there a chance that light bending from a micro black-hole can be used to create a microscope?

Comment: Where have you "seen" that black holes are used as microscopes? And what's the difference between the thing that you have "seen" and the thing that you haven't and you are asking about?

Comment: You are probably thinking about light bending in a gravitational field. You can also calculate the field strength using the Schwarzschild radius for a small object such as the Moon, but it is more difficult to describe a process whereby a small object is compressed into this radius.  Unless you can find such a process it is difficult to attach much importance to your optical lens.

Answer (score 4):

Gravitational lenses would be a very poor choice for use in an optical instrument. For optical instruments we require that the lenses focus parallel rays of light to a point - [the focal point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_(optics)):

[image: Lens]

This happens because the farther a light ray is from the optical axis the more strongly it is bent. However for a gravitational lens the farther the light is from the lensing object the more weakly it is bent. The light rays focussed by a micro black hole would look more like this:

[image: Gravitational lens]

Instead of a focal point a gravitational lens has a focal line, and this means it doesn't produce images in the way a conventional lens does. Consequently it would be of little use in a microsocope.

Comment: Rather than a flat screen, could we not have a cylindrical screen (i.e. a tube) around the dotted line towards right of the blackhole to capture the image? Also, what if we keep the object to be viewed close to the blackhole so the light rays on the left are not parallel but rather originate from a point.

Answer (score 0):

the [difference](http://pediaa.com/difference-between-telescope-and-microscope/) between a microscope and a telescope:

> microscopes are used to magnify small objects that are at a short
> distance from the viewer whereas telescopes are used to magnify large
> objects that are at a large distance from the viewer.

In gravitational lensing a black hole is used as a lens to see objects father away, so yes, in theory a small lens (a small black hole) can be used to view things that are close.